# Using an ActiveRecord class_name with pluck issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :detail_organization, class_name: "Organization"
end
```

and:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries
end
```

I can successfully:

```
> entry = Entry.last.detail_organization
  Entry Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "entries".* FROM "entries" ORDER BY "entries"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 69], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Organization:0x007fcabcabc
 id: 69,
 name: "Detail Office",
 code: "DFO",
 classification_id: 4,
 active: true,
 created_at: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 21:49:48 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 21:49:48 UTC +00:00>
```

but I've been working on a query that returns a rather large dataset being exported to xls requiring plucking. I've tried:

```
[111] pry(main)> @entries = Entry.scheduled_between(start_date, end_date).pluck('detail_organization.name')
   (0.6ms)  SELECT detail_organization.name FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "daily_logs" ON "daily_logs"."id" = "entries"."daily_log_id" WHERE ("daily_logs"."calendar_date" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)  [["calendar_date", "01/06/2017"], ["calendar_date", "01/06/2017"]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "detail_organization"
LINE 1: SELECT detail_organization.name FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "d...
               ^
: SELECT detail_organization.name FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "daily_logs" ON "daily_logs"."id" = "entries"."daily_log_id" WHERE ("daily_logs"."calendar_date" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)
from /Users/atfreeme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
```

with and without including the related organization table, but can't seem to make the association with pluck.

Interestingly enough:

```
[112] pry(main)> @entries = Entry.scheduled_between(start_date, end_date).pluck('detail_organization_id')
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "entries"."detail_organization_id" FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "daily_logs" ON "daily_logs"."id" = "entries"."daily_log_id" WHERE ("daily_logs"."calendar_date" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)  [["calendar_date", "01/06/2017"], ["calendar_date", "01/06/2017"]]
=> [60, 60, 69]
```

at least gets me ids.

Anyone with any pluck advice or possibly a new direction if I'm hopefully being descriptive enough about the problem? Not sure if this is PostgreSQL or ActiveRecord as an issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your query

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "detail_organization"

ActiveRecord is trying to search table `detail_organization` but you dont have the table in your database

you should query with `organizations` table as `detail_organization` is just an association name not a table name

```ruby
@entries = Entry.scheduled_between(start_date, end_date).joins(:detail_organization).pluck('organizations.name')
```

Comment: Problem is I have two columns in the Entry object as follows:

```=> #<Entry:0x007fc361c6ff30
 id: 21018,
 daily_log_id: 602,
 activity_id: 6,
 time_code_id: 1,
 organization_id: 1,
 job_title_id: 3,
 detail_organization_id: 69```